# Where NOT on eager loaded associtations

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am struggling with an active record query to select some specific data in my application. I have used 
https://robots.thoughtbot.com/activerecords-wherenot and
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html 
for reference.

My application has a `review` table (`belongs_to :application`) and users can review applications. I want to select Applications that were not reviewed by a specific user.

```
Application.includes(:reviews).references(:reviews).where('reviews.reviewer_id = 1')
# or
Application.includes(:reviews).references(:reviews).where(:reviews => { reviewer_id: 1 })
```

work both perfectly, but as mentioned, I want to select the inverse:

```
Application.includes(:reviews).references(:reviews).where.not(:reviews => { reviewer_id: 1 })
```

This does not give me the right data, it excludes applications that have no review at all. How can this be included as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it:-

```
 Application.includes(:reviews).references(:reviews).where("reviews.reviewer_id != ? OR reviews.reviewer_id IS NULL", 1)
```